# Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, next.js

I have already defined the types but I still get an error stating:

> Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type.

on this line for id, title and body

```
static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }) {
```

Here is my code:
import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
type Props={
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    postId: string;
}

export default class extends Component <Props> {
  static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }) {
    return { postId: id, title, body }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My blog post #{this.props.postId}</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) isn't part of `Component`, nothing tells TypeScript what it will receive or return, so you have to do that.

It looks like you're expecting the query string to contain `id`, `title`, and `body` (all strings). Since that's not quite what your `Props` type is, you can define that inline:

```
static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }: { query: {id: string, title: string, body: string} }) {
    return { postId: id, title, body };
}
```

...or as that inline type is a bit unwieldy:

```
type QueryParams = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    body: string;
};
```

then

```
static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }: { query: QueryParams }) {
    return { postId: id, title, body };
}
```

or even

```
type PartialContext = {
    query: {
        id: string;
        title: string;
        body: string;
    };
};
```

then

```
static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }: PartialContext) {
    return { postId: id, title, body };
}
```

---

I shold mention that your `getInitialProps` doesn't provide the `id` prop, but it's not listed as optional in your `Props` type, either.

---

Note that all of the above supply a type for the context parameter that Next.js will pass into `getInitialProps`, but they don't supply a type for the return value of `getInitialProps`. For completeness, you might want to supply that as well. Since what you're returning is only part of `Props`, the type would be `Partial<Props>`.

So for instance, using `QueryParams` (the middle option above, which is the one I like best):

```
type QueryParams = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    body: string;
};
```

then

```
static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }: { query: QueryParams }): Partial<Props> {
// Type of the parameter −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−− type of the return value
    return { postId: id, title, body };
}
```

---

Here's the above incorporated with your code:

```
type Props = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    postId: string;
};

type QueryParams = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  };

export default class extends Component <Props> {
    static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }: { query: QueryParams }): Partial<Props> {
        return { postId: id, title, body };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>My blog post #{this.props.postId}</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I added postId in the type PartialContext but it gives me error stating:
Property 'postId' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Comment: @Rebel - Why would you add `postId` to `PartialContext`? You're not receiving it. All of the types above are for the parameter, not the return value.

Comment: @Rebel - You haven't mentioned any error for `postId`. BTW, I updated the answer to mention you might want to provide the type of the return value, giving an example.

Comment: : Property 'postId' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Comment: @Rebel - Where are you getting that error? It seems odd, given that you're telling React what your props type is via `Component <Props>` (please double check your code actually has that). (But again, this all seems separate from the question you asked about implicit any types for the destructured parameters.)

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have pasted your code. I am getting this error on my return statement:
<h1>My blog post #{this.props.postId}</h1>

Error: Property 'postId' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

I have even updated my code now if you want to have a look of maybe where I am going wrong

Comment: When I try to add your updated code it gives me error with Partial<Props> as well. Error:Cannot find name 'Props'. Also the error for this.props.postId persists

Comment: @Rebel - I've rolled back the question edit trying to incorporate the above. We don't do that on SO, it makes the question and answer not make any sense to people in the future. In that edit, though, you've removed several things from your code: `Props` and (as I said above) `Component <Props>`. You just have `export default class Post extends Component  {`. I didn't say to remove anything. You need those things to tell TypeScript what your component's props are. If you remove them, TypeScript assumes React's default props, which don't have `postId`. You want to put them back. :-)

Comment: @Rebel - I've updated the answer to show one of the solutions I gave above in context with the rest of your code.